# Does listening to English learning clips help to improve "Listening" skill?

Tags: american-english, listening

I want to improve my listening skill in order to understand speaking of *native* English speakers. For this I have searched  in the Internet and Youtube clips and finally figured out listening to English conversations, movies, clips etc might be very helpful for improving this skill.

So, I am here to ask a couple of questions related to this matter.

- Does listening to *same* clips over and over again help or I should listen to new one once I am done with previous one?
- How many times at least should I listen to audio files per day? (How long time should I spend per day?)
- What should I do when I have stuck somewhere in the video (cannot parse what they are talking)? I should go ahead or I should not until understand all prior part of video

I have already noticed that this question might be off-topic because of its opinion-based nature, if this is so, please tell me the right Stack Exchange site which this question is on-topic at.

Note that my primarily focus is on American English not any other types of English.

Any answer would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: This question will surely be closed.  I have provided you a link, however, to send you on your journey.  See my answer, below.  Goodbye and good luck!

Comment: You seem to be a very motivated learner.  Looking forward to future questions from you!  Also, your English is very good.  I think you might find that *Answering* questions will further your learning experience more than you could ever imagine.  Just choose interesting questions and do a lot of research to back up your answers!

Comment: Listen as often as you want, to the same things or different--even if you are understanding little. Just hearing the sound combinations (whether in individual, words or phrases, but especially in dialogue and descriptive material (narration)) will help get your mind used to the English sound system, including stress, tones, patterns, pauses, rythms; and it will sink in to your brain even if you cannot understand a single word. Of course, understanding what you hear is also important, but don't think you have to understand anything or everything before listening to more. /M.A. TESOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience:

> Does listening to same clips over and over again help or I should listen to new one once I am done with previous one?

As long as you understand a certain clip, move on. The more word patterns and vocalizations you learn, the better.

> How many times at least should I listen to audio files per day? (How long time should I spend per day?)

As much as you can without getting discouraged.

> What should I do when I have stuck somewhere in the video (cannot parse what they are talking)? I should go ahead or I should not until understand all prior part of video?

This is where some assistance might help.

> 1) Try to watch videos where the actions tend to follow what is being spoken. For example, an actor gets into a taxi and says "Take me to the airport and hurry". Even if you do not understand every word just by listening, the actions will help you grasp the correct word. After you hear and can recognize the same word a few times, it should stick in your memory.
>
> 2) Try to watch videos that have subtitles in the same language as the speech (not translations). But don't follow them unless you get stuck on a word.
>
> 3) Try to watch videos that have slow clear speech patterns. Try to stay away from heavy accents, fast or slurred speech etc. For music, slow, clear pronunciation (something like ballads as opposed to hard rock). Major network news programs are also good.